# Can the MSE value determines if a model is more performant than another one?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, mse

I have to use the same training set and I have to find two models, one of the family ${()=}$ and one of the family ${()=+\frac{7}{10}}$. After found these models, can I say that the model with the smallest MSE is the best one? Or they have the same value? I'm very confused.

Comment: “Best” at what?

Comment: @Dave in accuracy

Comment: “Accuracy” meaning what? Often, “accuracy” refers to the proportion of observations that have the correct category predicted. However, what you’ve written makes no mention of a categorical outcome.